# DRF SerializerMethodField not updating the DateTimeField

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-3.0

I have a **TaskUpdateSerializer** that should be converting received date from format to another then update this date "converted date"

but I've noticed that django not complaining or raising any errors when i pass invalid date data to it and also not updating the data

name field update works fine except deadline field

### serializers.py

```
class TaskUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    deadline = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['name', 'deadline']


    def get_deadline(self, obj):
        deadline = self.context['request'].data.get('deadline')
        # try to convert deadline if its in Wed, Mar 10, 2021 7:19 PM format
        try:
            # convert giving date to datetime in this format Wed, Mar 10, 2021 7:19 PM
            d = datetime.strptime(deadline, '%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
            # convert it to 2021-3-10 7:48:22 format
            r = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
            return r # or return "blabla" works fine also
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
        return obj.deadline
```

### views.py

```
class TaskUpdate(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.TaskUpdateSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'task_id'
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
```

### models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    started = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Your `deadline` is readonly, so it is not intended to update the deadline.

Comment: I removed the readonly still the same

Comment: yes, because a method of course can only be readonly, you can not algorithmically "revert" the function.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean be cannot revert the function